# error 1242 subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem with my database homework. I need to write a subquery that will display the ISBN and title of book that have a category that starts with the letter ‘S’.

tables: BOOK(ISBN, Category, Title, Description, Edition, PublisherID) and CATEGORY(CatID, CatDescription)

keys: BOOK(ISBN_PK, Category_FK) and CATERGORY(CatID_PK)  ---> Category=CatID

For now I have some code but it returns an error. Because I'm doing this HW in advance and we still didn't learn subqueries I found most of the solutions to my problems online. Please help.

My code:

```
SELECT ISBN, title FROM book WHERE category LIKE (SELECT catdescription FROM category WHERE catdescription LIKE 's%')
```

Comment: `LIKE` expects a single argument, not a list.

Comment: A note on schema design: if Book.category is a foreign key to Category.CatID, it might be preferable to name it Book.CatID. This way the correspondence is immediately obvious. It also opens the possibility to use a [Natural Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Natural_join).

Comment: It also would make it obvious that a `book.category` does not correspond to a `category.catdescription`. You will want to do `select CatID` in the subquery, rather than `select catedescription`.

Comment: I agree, but this was given to us by a professor, so we can not change the attribute names. For the previous questions on the homework I was confused by the different names of the attributes but still I can't do anything about that so need to work with already stated attribute names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can join both tables rather than using subquery,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    book a
        INNER JOIN category b
            ON a.Category = b.CatID
WHERE   b.CatDescription LIKE 'S%'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

---

Consider using `FULLTEXTSEARCH` rather than `LIKE` if you are using `MyISAM` engine.

Comment: Joining tables is the heart of relational databases.

Comment: The question states that he needs to use a subquery.

Comment: @JoelNelson yes, but i'm getting another better way than subquery. You can add it on your answer how to do it using a subquery.

Comment: Thanks to the solution, but I need to use the subquery. Although your code works just as it is.

Comment: Try this, WHERE CATEGORY IN (SELECT CATID FROM CATEGORY WHERE CATDESCRIPTION LIKE 's%')

Answer (score 0):

change LIKE   to IN

```
   SELECT ISBN, title FROM book WHERE title IN (SELECT catdescription FROM category WHERE catdescription LIKE 's%')
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT ISBN, title FROM book WHERE ISBN IN (SELECT catdescription FROM category WHERE catdescription LIKE 's%')
OR title IN (SELECT catdescription FROM category WHERE catdescription LIKE 's%')
```

Comment: because you choosed category to be like.. when category is table name, i guess you want make title which like ...., try my updated answer

Comment: Still nothing. The output should give me the ISBN and title that have the corresponding category that begins with "s" letter. I will now try to upload image of the diagram and the needed output if I can.

Comment: Can't upload the images but here is the link to them 

[link](http://imageshack.us/a/img199/7463/outputhw6.jpg)
[link](http://imageshack.us/a/img94/8230/diagramhw6.jpg)

Comment: from those data in the picture what result you want get ?

Comment: Nope. JW 웃 has the right answer. It should be WHERE category IN (SELECT catID FROM category WHERE catdescription LIKE 's%'). 
But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use like on a sub query.  More than likely, just changing to the following query would also work.

```
SELECT ISBN, title 
  FROM book 
  WHERE category in (SELECT catdescription 
                      FROM category WHERE catdescription LIKE 's%')
```

This assumes that the book.category field corresponds to the category.catdescription field.

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't work if the subquery returned one string? The error seems to say that's the problem here. Not that it would be wise to do so...

Comment: Well, now you've interested me.  It does work, but only if there is one result, and it would only make sense if the catdescription was concatenated with a wild card string.  I've never needed it before...